# How to show test results in the console?

Tags: github-actions, pharo

In a GitHub Actions CI server I'm running `./pharo pharo.image test --fail-on-failure --junit-xml-output my-package` to run a test suite. The problem is that when a test fails I just can see a console message saying that "Tests do not pass!", but no details on which ones or what happened, and I cannot reproduce locally nor look at the XML. Is there a way to show the failing tests and their stack traces?

I'm running on Pharo 8

Comment: Why can't you look at the XML? Didn't it get attached as an artifact? If not, why not attach it yourself with a step that runs even if previous steps have failed?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look, how console output looks like in case of project, which I maintain. I don't use junit xml output, but terminal output, see example here: https://github.com/exercism/pharo-smalltalk/actions/runs/4161261683/jobs/7199033685#step:4:563

CI action for this defined here:
https://github.com/exercism/pharo-smalltalk/blob/main/.smalltalk.ston
and: here: https://github.com/exercism/pharo-smalltalk/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml

Quite recent wiki update on GH actions and Pharo here: https://github.com/pharo-open-documentation/pharo-wiki/blob/master/General/GithubActions.md